# List<char>.toString no convierte correctamente

Tags: c#, linq, validación, lista

Tengo una lista de `char`, la cual quiero guardar en un *string* con el método `ToString`.

El problema es que me guarda cualquier cosa:

[image: Captura mientras está compilando]

Para mayor información, el método, lo que hace es recibir el *string* cambiado de un `TextBox`, evalúa si existe algún caracter no entero dentro del *string*, y si existe lo quita (encontrando el caracter, creando una lista con los caracteres del *string* recibido, removiendo de la lista el caracter que coincida con el encontrado, que es no entero, luego devolviendo la lista a *string* y mostrándola en el `TextBox`).

¿Por qué guarda mal el *string*?

Comment: Hola Facundo. Gracias por la pregunta, y parece que ya recibistes una buena respuesta. Nada mas te comento que siempre se prefiere que el código lo incluyas en texto. Si quieres incluir una imagen del código adicionalmente, no hay problema. Pero sin el código en texto, entonces no podemos copiar el código para probarlo, por ejemplo.

Comment: ArtEze lógico, gracias por aclararmelo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `ToString` es un método heredado de la clase `Object` que devuelve una cadena que representa el objeto. Por defecto este método devuelve el nombre completo del tipo de objeto.

Algunos tipos sobrescriben este método para que tenga un comportamiento diferente, pero no es el caso de las listas genéricas. Por eso al llamar al método `ToString` el resultado es el nombre del tipo de objeto.

Si quieres convertir a `string` una lista de caracteres puedes utilizar el método `Concat`:

```
string recortado = string.Concat(recortar);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó perfecto. Sé que en lo posible no se debe usar la caja de comentarios para decir gracias, pero no encuentro otra forma de dejar claro que el tema ya se solucionó.

Comment: De nada @FacundoYuffrida. La forma correcta es marcar la respuesta como aceptada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la manera en la que abordas el problema no es la más eficiente. Yo te recomiento que simplemente valides si el caracter digitado es un número o no, y en caso de que no lo sea, no agregarlo al `perfectosTextbox` (en el evento KeyPress). Por ejemplo:

```
public static void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Esto haría que `textBox1` solo acepte números, que al final es lo que buscas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero en este caso prefiero la opción que comentó Asier ya que inicialmente el textBox tiene cargada una frase: "Ingrese el número aquí", y usando string.Concat me aseguro que al modificar ese texto original, se borren todos los caracteres no numéricos.

Comment: De todos modos, muchas gracias, estaba buscando la manera de usar la variable e hace tiempo, a ver si era igual que en Java

Answer (score 0):

puedes emplear expresiones regulares de la siguiente forma para eliminar los caracteres numéricos

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(perfectosTextBox.Text, @"[\d-]", string.Empty, RegexOptions.None);
```

Y para eliminar los no numéricos

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(perfectosTextBox.Text, @"[^0-9]", string.Empty, RegexOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

recortar.Tostring te retorna el literal del tipo "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char]"

para convertir la coleccion de char a string

```
 recortar =new String(recortar.ToArray())
```